# Indexing column and row returns an incorrect value

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am working with a CSV file using pandas. This CSV file is very large, and has the first row as GPS Coordinates, and the first column as GPS coordinates. Then all values correspond to the GPS coordinates.

**CSV Example**
(The actual CSV is 336 x 481)

```
       , 1.123, 2.123, 3.123
10.123 , NaN  , .2345, NaN
11.123 , .4353, NaN  , .2568
12.123 , .7653, NaN  , 1.456
```

**Problem**
I have written a few functions attempting to create a dictionary with GPS tuples as keys and the corresponding values as the mapped values. The code executes correctly, and it returns the dictionary, but when I checked the values against my CSV, the values don't match.

**Code**

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('201501.csv')

class csvRead(object):

    def getRow(self):
        with open('201501.csv') as csvfile:
            readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            for row in readCSV:
                return row[1:]

    def getColomn(self):
        x_coord = df['Fill']
        return x_coord

    def test(self):
        df = pd.read_csv('201501.csv')
        return df


def yCoord():
    y_list_base = csvRead()
    y_list_string = y_list_base.getRow()
    y_list = [float(i) for i in y_list_string]
    return y_list

def xCoord():
    x_list_base = csvRead()
    x_list_string = x_list_base.getColomn()
    x_list = [float(i) for i in x_list_string]
    return x_list

def createCoords():
    csv = csvRead()
    df = csv.test()
    x_list = xCoord()
    y_list = yCoord()
    coord_dict = {}
    for x_coord in x_list:
        for y_coord in y_list:
            x_loc = x_list.index(x_coord)
            y_loc = y_list.index(y_coord)
            value = df.iloc[x_loc,y_loc]
            current_pair = (x_coord,y_coord)
            coord_pair = current_pair
            coord_dict[coord_pair] = value
    return coord_dict
```

Let me know if you see any errors in logic or code that I can fix.

Comment: What is desired output of your sample data?

Comment: Could you provide an example of what the resulting dict looks like with this code, and what it should look like?

Comment: @bschlueter Due to the size of the dictionary it outputs, I only check a few of the points, and notice that they do not match up, so I can't show you what the entire dictionary should look like, but I can show you the csv and the dictionary that this data returns. What is the best way for me to show you this information?

Comment: Just a simple case, such as the expected result from the example csv you included, should be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need the result available to pandas, something like this would work:

```
import csv

coords = {}
with open('201501.csv') as csvfile:
    read_csv = csv.reader(csvfile)
    x_coords = read_csv.next()[1:]

    for row in read_csv:

        for x_coord, column in zip(x_coords, row[1:]):
            value = None if 'NaN' in column else float(column)
            coords[(float(row[0]), float(x_coord))] = value
```

With the sample input, this populates coords with:

```
{(10.123, 1.123): None,
 (10.123, 2.123): 0.2345,
 (10.123, 3.123): None,
 (11.123, 1.123): 0.4353,
 (11.123, 2.123): None,
 (11.123, 3.123): 0.2568,
 (12.123, 1.123): 0.7653,
 (12.123, 2.123): None,
 (12.123, 3.123): 1.456}
```

Comment: It always amazes me how people are able to do so much with so little code, sorry I didn't get back to you about the output, but the way you showed it is exactly what I was going to put. One issue though, when I use this on my csv, it only does this for the first row, any ideas how I would fix this?

Comment: Do you mean you only get `{(10.123, 1.123): None,
 (10.123, 2.123): 0.2345,
 (10.123, 3.123): None}` or something similar when given different data? You'd have to provide more information. It could be that the csv is too large or corrupt as this code works for the sample data provided. If this works, feel free to accept and +1.